# Test Error - NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/hamcrest/Matchers

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-espresso, android-testing

I am using Espresso for Instrumented Test but got this error on the Stack Trace:

[image]

The error being caused by a missing class as shown below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hamcrest.Matchers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~vnZzxGNKnS4V6YkEf4falA==/com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.reactive.test-K_x0_yJ0hJeDHaJkDmHXRw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~oeYx2MgTcILbk-vq_WPx1A==/com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.reactive-0wMHYEe95hx_1cnbdAoZAw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories
```

It first occurred immediately after I added this code in the Fragment Test:

[image]

These are my relevant Libs on the Gradle:

[image]

I have these imports:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.testing.launchFragmentInContainer
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `espresso-core` dependency includes the hamcrest matchers, and you won't need to separately declare `hamcrest`

Comment: Hi @agoff you won't believe it if I told you that the error was being caused by `espresso-contrib`. I removed it and the project now runs fine. You are also right that `espresso-core` includes hamcrest matchers. Thanks lots for looking into my issue.

Comment: adding dependency androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2" works for me. A simple solution that can keep using newer espresso version. I'm using version 3.5.1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TLDR answer**, you don't need to downgrade the whole espresso setup
there is a Hamcrest version conflict with transitive dependencies which can be easily solved:

If you are using:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'

//change it to:
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'
```

if you are using:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0'

//change it to:
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.3.0"
```

You should still be able to keep espresso core at the higher 3.4.0 version

---

If you want to understand, here is the longer explanation:

To see what is going on under the hood we can use the dependencies gradle task to print out the dependency tree, in android studio terminal:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

We can run it twice, using the dependencies at the two version levels and can check the differences.

- At several points there are requests for hamcrest libraries version 1.3 which match most of the common android dependencies.
- On the left side (dependency tree for v3.3.0) **every hamcrest transitive dependency is provided as requested**, no surprise it works!
- On the right side (dependency tree for v3.4.0) we can see some of the requests got  "substitute" hamcrest libraries at a higher version which, in this case, does not work.

[[image: Gradle dependency tree comparison1]

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking a deeper look into this, goes a long way in helping the community.

Comment: @Tonnie no worries, if we get an understanding of the underlying issues I'm sure that knowledge will come in handy later ;) 
In this case, the "how-to" may help someone else out of some other transitive depency problem

Comment: Updating your dependencies to 3.5.0-alpha03 seems to fix the problem

Comment: @Goldorak84 - updating androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib to 3.5.0-alpha03 did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: This is nice.  But it doesn't give the solution, which is to include this in build.gradle file ```androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'``` 
Why does this work anyway?  If  the problem is that espresso wants hamcrest 1.3 but is getting 2.2??

Comment: Same for me. I added `androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'` and now it works.

Comment: adding dependency `androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2"` works for me. A simple solution that can keep using newer `espresso` version. I'm using version 3.5.1

Answer (score 15):

I didn't try the accepted answer, but some of the replies saved my a$$, just add:

```
androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2"
```

Comment: adding dependency androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2" works for me. A simple solution that can keep using newer espresso version. I'm using version 3.5.1

Answer (score 6):

After struggling for a while I realized the error is being caused by `espresso-contib` and `espresso-accessibility` dependencies. My espresso version was the latest **version 3.4.0-alpha05**.

I removed them and tests passed.

**Before** including `espresso-contrib` & `espresso-accessibility`

```
/*core contains matches and view assertions, included by default on android project*/
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"

//testing code for advanced views such as recyclerview and Date picker
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espressoVersion"
```

**After** comment out on both `espresso-contrib` & `espresso-accessibility`

```
//core contains matches and view assertions, included by default on android project
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
//testing code for advanced views such as recyclerview and Date picker
//androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
//androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espressoVersion"
```

Comment: To Test RecyclerView etc I downgraded to `espressoVersion = '3.3.0'`

Comment: Thanks, This worked. Don't know why this would be the case as its based on the google documentation to add those dependencies.

Comment: I seemed to have solved it using `androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2"`

Comment: adding dependency androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2" works for me. A simple solution that can keep using newer espresso version. I'm using version 3.5.1